# Next.js SSR with local SQLite: "unable to open database file"

Tags: sqlite, next.js

I'm creating a small Next.js app with a local ~250MB SQLite db. I put the `mydb.sqlite` file in the root folder of my project, and import it using [`better-sqlite3`](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3):

```
import sqlite from 'better-sqlite3';

export const db = sqlite('./mydb.sqlite');
```

I have a couple of server-side rendered (SSR) routes that query data from the DB and renders them in a React page. This works well locally with `next dev` on localhost:3000. However, when I deploy to Vercel, and visit the same SSR page, I get the error at runtime:

```
ERROR   SqliteError: unable to open database file
```

It's worthy to note that since the DB is >100MB, I cannot commit it to git. Instead, in my build phase, I download it:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "build": "curl $DB_URL -o mydb.sqlite && next build",
},
```

I also have some statically-generated (SSG) pages which query the DB, and those pages are correctly generated. Only SSR pages have that error at runtime.

Is there something I forgot to do? Must I commit the db to git? Should I configure the webpack config?

I looked on the internet for sqlite + next.js, but it always involve prisma; I prefer plain SQL queries.

Comment: Interesting use case. Is your data mostly static, that you are not looking for some kind of db server? Have you thought about replacing it with just plenty of simple json file instead? If sqlite compreses it's db file, having plain text json will take more space in first commit; but will generate less noise on every change - unchanged data files will be reused form commit to commit.

Comment: The db is updated once every 6 months or so, I don't need git for it. It's obviously accessed in read-only in the next.js app. I have thought of a bunch of JSON files, but see it as a fallback solution, as it doesn't offer as much flexibility as SQL queries.

Comment: If it doable, some trail for the answer should be in vercel logs. Or they directly run `next build` ignoring what ever you put in the npm build script.

Answer (score 2):

SSR pages on vercel are rendered by their serverless functions. These functions don't have your sqllite file layered inside and thus you get the unable to open error.

Comment: so no solution?

Comment: 1. Ditch vercel and do a custom deployment on something like fly.io

Comment: 2. Upload the sqllite db to some blob store and initialize it on every API call